# Spoiled image of plotly graph after being downloaded from a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I have the shiny app below in which I want to download a plotly plot using `downloadhandler()`. But as you will see when I run the app in web browser and download the image the lower section of the histogram is missing. Why does this happen? Can this be fixed or be downloaded alternativelly? In case you wonder why I have used `uiOutput()` for download button and the movies dataset it is because this is how my original and more complex app works. Before you begin:

```
 library(webshot)
 install_phantomjs()


#uir.r
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2movies) # movies is no longer contained within ggplot2 https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2movies/index.html

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Movie Ratings!"),
  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("down")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("trendPlot")
  )
))
#server.r
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2movies) # movies is no longer contained within ggplot2 https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2movies/index.html

shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  output$down<-renderUI({
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function(){

        paste0(paste0("pic"), ".png")
      },
      content = function(file) {
            export(reg(), file=file)
      }) 
    downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
  })

  reg<-reactive({
    movies
    # Create axes titles as lists
    x <- list(
      title = "A",
      dtick = 5 
    )
    y <- list(
      title = "B"
    )
    # Create the plotly histogram

    plot_ly(alpha = 0.9) %>%
      add_histogram(x = as.factor(movies$rating)) %>%
      # Add titles in plot and axes
      layout(barmode = "overlay",title = "SAD",xaxis=x,yaxis=y)
  })
  output$trendPlot <- renderPlotly({
    reg()

  })
})
```

SPOLIED IMAGE
[image]

Comment: Weird. For an alternative way to download, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314307/download-plotly-using-downloadhandler/53317200#53317200

Comment: I have already tried to implement it here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54593775/error-in-plotly-graph-download-from-a-shiny-app-when-using-javascript But I would like to use a downloadhandler instead of an actionbutton which will be activated from uiOutput. Can you help?

Comment: I did that using javascript. Anyway I leave this Q because it is about a different issue.

Comment: Using [orca](https://plot.ly/r/static-image-export/) (as mentioned to you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54586780/download-a-dynamic-plotly-graph-using-dynamic-downloadhandler-from-a-shiny-app) already) is not an option? Running your code gives me a warning `Warning: 'export' is deprecated. Use 'orca' instead. See help("Deprecated")`